# TextBox writing on one line only

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

When ever I type something IN a textbox, than I click the button, I have a writeline. Is there a way to assign that one text box to only the first line, and the second text box to the second line on a notepad? So when you type something new in it, it will delete what you previously had on the first line, than add the new thing in the text box?

I am using.

```
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file =      My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:/Users/Nick/Documents/Dra.txt", True)

    file.WriteLine(NameBasic)
    file.WriteLine(LastBasic)
    file.Close()
```

Comment: Look at the little pop-up hints Intellisense provides you as you type: `OpenTextFileWriter(file As String, append As Boolean) As System.IO.StreamWriter` you are passing True for the append parameter so, it doesnt start a new file.  Also, that is not a valid path name and not the correct way to get s user path - use `Environment.GetFolderPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second argument in `OpenTextFileWriter()` method is `append`. It means that strings will be appended to the end of the file if it get `True` value.

Try to use `False` instead:

`file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:/Users/Nick/Documents/Dra.txt", False)`

**UPD**

```
    Dim read As String = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim num As Integer
    Integer.TryParse(read, num)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, also is there a way to do something like `Dim read as integer = Readline(1)`

again thank you

Comment: There is a `Console` static class. It has `ReadLine()` method.
See my answer updated.
You should set value from `ReadLine()` to a string variable. And then parse it to integer value.

Comment: Wait so lets say I wanted to make a variable of what is on the first line, or the second line. would I use the example you gave me? @Vladimir Seryhk

Comment: Sorry, could not get you. Trying to explain. `ReadLine()` returns `String` so if you setting the value came from `ReadLine()` to `Integer` variable and it is not valid number, you'll get an exception. To deal with that, you need to store value from `ReadLine()` to `String` variable and then try to parse it to `Integer`. In that way you should use 1st and 3rd lines. If you already have an `Integer` variable it is not necessary to declare one more (2nd line).